# In R, unambiguous format error when removing "NA"

Tags: r

I'm trying to simply convert the NA values of a column into blanks in preparation for Excel export. My code returns the error below:

```
> class(manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE)
[1] "Date"
> head(manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE)
[1] "2016-10-23" NA           "2016-10-23" NA           NA           NA          
> manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE[is.na(manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE)] <- ''
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

the column MIN_SAIL_DATE was a actually a computed column from a sqlQuery{RODBC} function and then join{plyr} to another table. the column was originally in the POSIX format and I forced it to Date.

EDIT:::

This following code solved my problem with the NAs when executed immediately after querying the data:

```
next_sail$MIN_SAIL_DATE <- as.character.Date(next_sail$MIN_SAIL_DATE)
```

the following join was used to append two detail columns from `next_detail` onto `manifest` on both `person_num` and `MIN_SAIL_DATE`=`SAIL_SAIL_DATE`:

```
manifest <- merge(manifest, next_detail, by.x = c('PERSON_NUM', 'MIN_SAIL_DATE'), by.y= c('PERSON_NUM', 'SAIL_SAIL_DTE'), all.x = TRUE)
```

when the format change happens before the join, I lose the NAs but also lose the appended data. when the format change is moved AFTER the merge I get the original `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

A sample of the data is below. then the NAs are removed i lose the circled codes from the join. im assuming its a format issue

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQKOw.png)

Comment: You have a couple of choices, the first being for you to use the `na=''` option of `write.table` (or whatever write function you are using).  You can also convert `manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE` to a character vector before you set `NA` to the empty string.  It is complaining because you are attempting to set some elements of a `Date` vector to the empty string. The first choice would likely be best.  The default is `na = "NA"` and you just need to set it to the empty string.

Comment: perfect. I guess the problem just stemmed from my misunderstanding of the error. I changed the column to character format and we're all good. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the write function you are using (e.g. `write.csv`) use the `na` option as follows to set the `NA` character

```
write.csv(manifest_final, your_output_file, na = '')
```

You can of course include whatever other options you are using in `write.csv`.  This option should be available in the other `write.*` functions as well.

**EDITS**

The issue with

```
manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE[is.na(manifest_final$MIN_SAIL_DATE)] <- ''
```

is that you are attempting to set a `Date` vector element to a `character` string.

Although, I think the above solution (using `na=`) is the way to go, you can also convert the `MIN_SAIL_DATE` column to a string, then set the `NA` columns to the empty string.

Comment: this answer did not explicitly solve my problem as i am not using write.csv but the above suggestion to convert column to character solved my problem

Comment: @Gino The other `write.*` functions should also support the `na=` option,  are you using one of those ?  If so, that is easier than changing data types; in general, you my have many columns of different types that contain NA.

Comment: no im using a funtion in COMCreate that opens excel, writes the data into the file, saves and emails. I am unaware if there is a na= option exists there but I do not believe so. Also, I am still having an issue with the format because when I change it to character my merges do not compile correctly. when i format after the merge I still get the error

Comment: @Gino It is unclear to me what issue you are having, is this the same as the original question ?

Comment: yep, i changed the column to character and was able to remove the NA, but then since the format was unoriginal my joins (not pictured and occurring after the format change) did not return any data. when i move the format change AFTER the join in the code, I get the right data but then get the original error posted above

Comment: @Gino For your first issue (issues joining), it would help to see what you are joining to and on (and how you are doing it, i.e. a reproducible example).  For the second issue (after joining) can you provide some output data to reproduce this (use `dput` on a small sample to reproduce)?  You are likely having a similar issue with data types.